# Origin of plurals and possessives

Tags: etymology, grammatical-number, possessives

What is the origin of English plurals and possessives? English plurals look more French plurals, but I am not sure that is where they come from. As for possessives, I don't know where they come from.

Comment: French plurals are from the accusative case of Latin. I promise you that English’s are not.

Comment: By "What is the origin of plurals and possessives?" do you mean (a) What did the pl & poss suffixes sound like in Old English and Proto-Germanic? (b) How did English get to have plural and possessive inflections? (c) Why are the English plural and possessive morphemes identical in form?

Comment: Have you attempted to research this yourself first? You'd likely find more information that way if you know where to look.

Comment: @John Lawler: those are the questions are I am asking

Comment: @4rkain3: have looked up German grammar on Wikipedia, and in short it says that one of the modern German plurals is with an s. Wiki's "Early Modern English" does not address this. I have looked elsewhere and haven't found anything answer's what happened.

Comment: @James Mohler Okay. I just wanted to make sure you did research it first, as in many cases that would provide an answer.

Comment: @4rkain: no offense taken. I think my question would have been better if I would have also also included 3rd person singular present verbs.

Comment: Are you somehow thinking that all three of these /əz/ inflections somehow have the same origin — like in *he earns* versus *the sponges* versus *Bill’s house*, or in *he sits* versus *the bats* versus *Kit’s knits*? They certainly do not, so that’s three separate questions. But phonologically they do share in common whether they become /(ə)z/ or /(ə)s/, in that the voicing is determined by the extant voicing of the end of the word the suffix gets applied to. Where have you researched this, and what did you find there? Have you examined the language of *Beowulf*, which is **true** Old English?

Comment: @JamesMohler: Those are three different questions; which one do you need an answer to? There are three different answers.

Comment: @John Lawler: (c) is the more important to me

Comment: @John Lawler: (c) is the most important to me

Comment: Thank you. The short answer is that they fell together when most of the other inflections were lost. Many, many Germanic and Indo-European inflections used _-s_; it was one category of plural noun marker in just about every IE language. Possessive _-s_, on the other hand, has a very checkered history. And the 3SgPr _-s_ is a Scandinavian loan, replacing original OE _-th_, which came via Grimm's Law from PIE 3sgPr _-t_.

Comment: Sounds like a dupe to me. The same thing seems to have been answered very very recently. Let me check, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that they fell together when most of the other inflections were lost.

For the plural, many, many Germanic and Indo-European inflections used -s; it was one category of plural noun marker in just about every IE language. It was the only marker left when the others were elided.

Possessive '-s', on the other hand, has a very checkered history, which I won't touch.

As to the superficially related third person singular verb inflection, the '-s' is a Scandinavian loan, replacing original OE '-th', which came via Grimm's Law from PIE third person singular '-t'.